# Google Play Console Internal Testing: Test Card not showing

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I have set up my app for internal testing and added the email used as a licensed tester and app tester in the Google Play Console. But when clicking an IAP inside the app no test card appears.

I have tried removing all Google accounts, resetting Google Play/App data, and restarting the android device, but the testing card still does not appear.

Could anyone give me some guidance on what I may be doing wrong? Thank you.

[What appears when I click an IAP in the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ANhu.png)

Answer (score 3):

Waiting ~12 hours after adding the email address to the list of licensed testers in Google Play was the answer for me.